# I Have 2 Ubuntu options in Bios even after uninstalling the partition of elementary os freya in windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I've set the bios to automatically boot to windows 8.1 but there are **2 ubuntu options**  in the Bios even after I deleted the partition in which I installed elementary os freya by logging into windows 8.1. I tried "**bootrec /fixmbr**" and it shows **successful** but the **2 ubuntu options are still there in the Bios.** Also I am unable to boot from a dvd except from a usb. Neeed Help fast. Thnks in advance

Comment: How many files starting with `vmlinuz` do you have in your `/boot` directory?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify your situation. Do you have an Ubuntu installation on the machine? Can you boot into Linux? Also, you don't set the BIOS to boot an OS, are you talking about the boot loader? Which one? Windows' or GRUB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options in UEFI do not harm. It happens because both UEFI and update-grub wrote there. The best way to 'fix' it is to remove both items using efibootmgr and run 'sudo update-grub'.

```
sudo efibootmgr
```

You will see efi boot entries. Like Boot0001, Boot0000, etc.

To remove an entry do, e.g.

```
sudo efibootmgr -Bb 0000
```

Other options can be found by

```
man efibootmgr
```

Fail to boot from DVD is not related at all. It may be a DVD drive problem, or disk, etc.

Comment: So do you mean that i have to reinstall elementary os freya to do what you said above me?

Comment: No, I just gave a solution how to remove a double entry from efi.

Comment: I mean should i install elementary os to do what you said.

Comment: So you want to completely delete all linux installations from your pc and leave only Windows?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want to do

Comment: Then edit your question and make it more clear.

Comment: I did what u said however i tried deleting both ubuntu options but when I enter the Bios one of the 2 ubuntu options isn't deleted. Why is it like that?

Comment: It is because grub is still there. It is off topic here. You can replace grub with Windows boot loader.  It can be done from Windows.